# Como abrir uma janela dentro de um Frame principal?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Estou fazendo um programa e estou criando o *layout* manualmente com swing usando `GridBagLayout` e `GroupLayout`. Gostaria de saber como abrir uma janela dentro do programa que estou fazendo.

Por exemplo: Quando o usuário clicar no botão <kbd>Cadastrar Cliente</kbd>, o programa abrirá um janela acoplada no programa em um espaço determinado no interface principal, ao invés de abrir uma tela independente.

Não quero criar uma tela independente para cada item, mas queria uma tela principal do programa e o espaço todo dentro da tela principal seja preenchida com as outras sub telas de cadastros. Postei um exemplo do programa Corel Draw para mostrar apenas o que estou querendo e melhorar o entendimento de vocês:

<kbd>[image: Postei um exemplo do programa Corel Draw para mostrar apenas o que estou querendo e melhorar o entendimento de vocês]</kbd>

Comment: Ah, li melhor, basta adicionar um jpanel ali, e setar ele quando clicar no botao. Ao inves de criar varias janelas(JFrames), você cria containers(Jpanel), cada um pra uma tela diferente. Depois, basta alternar a visibildade de cada um de acordo com a chamada do botoes.

Comment: Você pode usar [`JInternalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). Em determinados casos você pode usar `JPanel`, mas se bem entendi seu problema, *internal frames* te darão mais flexibilidade, se não poderá ter que customizar muito um `JPanel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar [`JInternalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) para gerenciar suas telas de cadastros.

Um exemplo bem simples. Considere que você tem a sua tela principal, `MainFrame`, que tem um menu, algo assim:

[image: Tela Principal]

O código resumido necessário para criar esta tela seria mais ou menos isto:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4985498392168006224L;

    private final JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();

    public MainFrame() {
        super("Tela Principal");

        final int inset = 50;
        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        final Dimension dimension = new Dimension(screenSize.width / 3, screenSize.height / 2);
        this.setBounds(inset, inset, dimension.width - inset * 2, dimension.height - inset * 2);

        this.setContentPane(desktop);
        this.setJMenuBar(this.createMenuBar());

        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
    }

    // esse é o cara chamado ao acessarmos o menu, ou no seu caso, clicar no botão :)
    protected void createFrame() {
        final UsuarioInternalFrame frame = new UsuarioInternalFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (final PropertyVetoException e) {
            // trate a exceção conforme sua necessidade
        }
    }

}
```

Obs.: como a intenção não é apresentar o básico de swing, apenas o uso de [`JInternalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html), não irei colocar como criar o menu, abrir a tela principal, etc. =)

Ao irmos no menu **Cadastros** -> **Usuários**, exibiriamos uma [`JInternalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html):

[image: Tela do Usuário ao Abrir]

O evento do clique no menu, botão, etc., basicamente cria a *internal frame* que precisamos, o método `createFrame`, da nossa tela principal. O código da `UsuarioInternalFrame` é simples, algo assim:

```
public class UsuarioInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -619850559630326110L;

    public UsuarioInternalFrame() {
        super("Usuários", true, true, true, true);

        this.setSize(500, 300);

        this.setLocation(30, 30);
    }
}
```

Então você pode ter diversas *internal frames*, pode maximizá-las::

[image: Tela do Usuário Maximizada]

Minimizá-la:

[image: Tela do Usuário Minimizada]

Enfim, customizar conforme suas necessidades, como mesmo disse, fazer com que o tamanho dela fique apenas na área cinza do seu exemplo do Corel, term nas laterais os menus, uma tree, etc. Há diversas formas de fazer.

Isto é só um exemplo básico de como você pode usar as [`JInternalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html), podendo evoluir o exemplo, customizar conforme sua necessidade. Em determinados casos você pode usar `JPanel`, mas se bem entendi seu problema, *internal frames* te darão mais flexibilidade, se não poderá ter que customizar muito um `JPanel`.